# Remove from insertion

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I wonder how to remove an item from insertion.

I want to avoid the insertion of contact with lastName = 'B' but insert the others, How can I do it?, adding an error with

> record.addError

is a "all or none" so there are no way to avoid the insertion of a single record,

> Trigger.New.remove(1);

doesn't work because it is a only read collection (and it makes very sense because there is also a Trigger.NewMap referencing the same item)

### I will place some code because I think is the best way to explain:

### Trigger on Contact

```
trigger AvoidB on Contact (before insert) {

    for(Contact c : Trigger.new){

        if(c.lastName == 'B'){
            //c.addError('Is a B');

            Trigger.New.remove(1);
        }

    }
}
```

---

### Execute console

```
List<Contact> c = new List<Contact>();
c.add(new Contact(lastName = 'A'));
c.add(new Contact(lastName = 'B'));
c.add(new Contact(lastName = 'A'));
c.add(new Contact(lastName = 'A'));
c.add(new Contact(lastName = 'A'));

insert c;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with `addError()` as much as it is with `insert`.

That all or nothing behavior that is causing the entire batch to fail can be avoided by using `Database.insert(c,false);` instead of `insert c;`

The [SaveResult class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_saveresult) page in the documentation has a good overview of this pattern.

Comment: But I want to allow the items to be inserted and avoid the ones that doesn't match, all from the trigger
, Are there any way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the all or nothing behavior of a DML operation can only be determined when the call is initiated.

Comment: Ok, so in response to my question there are no way to avoid the insertion of a single item once in the trigger.

Comment: Right, all the trigger can do is mark a record as having an error, it can't remove the record from the list of records being inserted.